# Amazon Linux2 へ PostgreSQL + PostGIS をインストールしたい

Tags: postgresql, amazon-linux

Amazon Linux2 で PostgreSQL + PostGIS 環境を構築したいです

---

[【Ansible】PostgreSQL 12をAmazon Linux 2にインストールし、Ansible Playbook化する【PostgreSQL】](https://qiita.com/tmiki/items/00d22edc6a554f61bd04)

まず PostgreSQL のインストールに関してはこちらのブログを参考にしました
バージョン 12 になってますがいま 13 がでてるみたいなので 12 => 13 におきかえています

新規に立てた EC2 上で postgres インストール＆起動まではブログ通りでうまく行きました

```
sudo yum update -y

sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
sudo sed -i 's/\$releasever/7/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo
sudo yum install -y postgresql13 postgresql13-server
PGSETUP_INITDB_OPTIONS='--encoding=UTF-8 --locale=C' sudo /usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-setup initdb
sudo systemctl enable --now postgresql-13
```

PostGIS に関しては
[PostgreSQLにPostGISをセットアップする](https://qiita.com/is0me/items/f017ada614664205677a)
こちらのブログを参考にしました

まず epel が必要みたいなので

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
```

を実行しましたが

```
33 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
パッケージ epel-release は利用できません。
エラー: 何もしません


epel-release is available in Amazon Linux Extra topic "epel"

To use, run
# sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel

Learn more at
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras
```

といわれたので

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
```

を実行したところ一応インストールには成功しました

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
```

を行うと
`パッケージ epel-release-7-11.noarch はインストール済みか最新バージョンです`
といわれるようになったので同等のものが入ったんだと思います

続いて postgis 本体インストール
これもブログでは 30_12 になってますが 31 がでてるので 31_13 にしてます

```
sudo yum install -y postgis31_13
```

これもインストール自体は成功しました

postgis 拡張を有効にしようと

```
sudo su - postgres
psql -d postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

を実行したところ

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-13/lib/postgis-3.so": /lib64/libSFCGAL.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost7archive18text_iarchive_implINS0_13text_iarchiveEE4loadERSs
```

というエラーになってしまいます

後者のブログに

> 色々試した結果PostGISは2でも3でも、CentOS 7、PostgreSQL 12推奨です。
> 互換性の都合で、Amazon Linux、Amazon Linux 2は避けるべきです。

とかかれているんですが最終的なバッチ作業を既存の Amazon Linux2 で動かしたいので
どうしても Amazon Linux2 で動かしたいです

> PostGISでは、
> gcc, libxml2, gdal, geos, proj
> あたりが必要になりますが、個別にインストールすると互換性の問題で、CREATE EXTENSION postgisを実行するとエラーになります。
>
> gdal, geos, projは、pgdg-commonリポジトリのものを使いましょう。
> ※ sudo yum install postgis30_12では、gdal30-libs, geos38, proj70が入ります。

とあるんですがビルドやリンカー等の知識がなくて
具体的にどうすればいいかがわからないので助けていただけないでしょうか

よろしくお願いします

---

追記:

```
ldd /lib64/libSFCGAL.so.1
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc9d99000)
    libCGAL.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libCGAL.so.11 (0x00007faf4d395000)
    libCGAL_Core.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libCGAL_Core.so.11 (0x00007faf4d15c000)
    libmpfr.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libmpfr.so.4 (0x00007faf4cefe000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007faf4cc86000)
    libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007faf4ca75000)
    libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007faf4c853000)
    libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007faf4c64f000)
    libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007faf4c3e2000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007faf4c060000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007faf4bd20000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007faf4bb0a000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faf4b75f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faf4e080000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007faf4b557000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faf4b339000)
```

---

```
sudo rpm -ivh https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/boost-serialization-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

を実行してみたんですが

```
準備しています...              ################################# [100%]
    ファイル /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0 (パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64 から) は、パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-27.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 からのファイルと競合しています。
    ファイル /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.1.53.0 (パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64 から) は、パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-27.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 からのファイルと競合しています。
    ファイル /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization-mt.so.1.53.0 (パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64 から) は、パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-27.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 からのファイルと競合しています。
    ファイル /usr/lib64/libboost_wserialization.so.1.53.0 (パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64 から) は、パッケージ boost-serialization-1.53.0-27.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 からのファイルと競合しています。
```

といわれてしまいます
すでに入ってるものを無効にするにはどうすればいいんでしょうか

Comment: エラーメッセージ(undefined symbol)から察するに、boost serialization library がインストールされていない様です。Amazon Linux2 でパッケージが提供されているかもしれません(yum search で調べてみるなど)。

Comment: sudo yum install boost-serialization やってみたんですが パッケージ 「boost-serialization-1.53.0-27.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
何もしません」となりました。sudo yum install -y boost boost-devel だとインストールされましたがエラーは変わらずです

Comment: それでは `ldd /lib64/libSFCGAL.so.1` を実行して、その結果を追記して貰えますか？

Comment: CentOS 向けのパッケージである http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/boost-serialization-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64.rpm に含まれる `libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0` には `_ZN5boost7archive...` symbol が存在しています(これは `boost::archive::text_iarchive` メソッドに対応する linkage name です)。`boost-serialization-1.53.0-27.amzn2.0.5.x86_64` のパッケージファイルが入手できないので推測になりますが、PostgreSQL と同じ EL7 向けの boost-serialization パッケージをインストールする必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ダメ元で `postgis31_13` の代わりに `postgis30_13` を入れて試してみるか、`rpm -qf /lib64/libSFCGAL.so.1` でパッケージのバージョンを確認してみてください。

Comment: EC2新規に立ててブログ通り 30_12 で入れ直してみましたがエラー全く同じでした

Comment: rpm コマンドに `--replacepkgs` か `--replacefiles` オプションを付けるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: オプションをつけたところうまくいきました！

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄でのやり取りで終わらせず、回答として投稿することを検討してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで教えていただいた通り
boost-serialization のパッケージを置き換えたところエラーがでなくなりました

```
# install postgis
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y epel 
sudo rpm -ivh --replacepkgs --replacefiles http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/boost-serialization-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install -y postgis31_13 postgis31_13-client osm2pgsql --enablerepo=epel

# posgis 有効
sudo su - postgres
psql -d postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```